# When was the last Ajax request made?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Is it possible to check in JavaScript/ Jquery at what time the last Ajax request was made in JavaScript client side code?

Comment: Can't you just have a timestamp variable and update it with each ajax call? ;)

Comment: If you control all the reqs, it's up to you to log the timestamp. If you want to know what happens across all document scripts, I guess not though [`$.ajaxStart()`](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxStart/) may help you.

Answer (score 2):

You can add some logging in this way:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    beforeSend: function (jqXHR) {
        //ADD LOG LINES HERE TO SEE TIME
    },
});
```

This way, beforeSend will execute for each ajax call and log to console.
Your log line should include timestamp.

Comment: Keep in mind that `beforeSend` function is used to access the raw request before sending it [e.g. to inject new headers], and not as a pre-request callback.

Answer (score 0):

You can set up `$(document).ajaxStart` or `$.ajaxSetup` so every time you make a request, you can do something, for example:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    $(document).ajaxStart(function() {
        window.lastAjaxRequest = new Date();
    });
    // or
    $.ajaxSetup({
        beforeSend: function (req) {
            window.lastAjaxRequest = new Date();
        }
    });
</script>
```

Then you'll be able to use `lastAjaxRequest` wherever you want.

Hope it helps!